# overshoot and undershoot on 3 volt pulse

Tags: operational-amplifier, fpga, circuit-protection, surge-protection, over-voltage-protection

i am interfacing a system, this system output signal of 200ns digital pulse with repetition time of every 3ms. Ideal voltage of signal would be 0v to 3.3V but signal coming from system have high overshoot and undershoot value (value upto +5 to -2V). and i want to interface this signal with Xilinx 7 series FPGA(artix) with bank voltage of 3.3V. Attach is signal shape i get from system.
[image: Noisy signal from system]

1. So first question is If i don't put any protection circuit would my IO pin of FPGA will burnout or what will happen. as maximum voltage limit as per 7 series FPA for 3.3V bank is -0.5 to 3.8V.
2. Second question is what will be good protection circuit for this overshoot and undershoot protection.
3. is there any recommended OPAMP IC which will handle 200ns pulse easily

I need circuit which will handle 200ns pulse easily.

Comment: What is the impedance of the source driving the signal and what connects it between the source and your FPGA?

Comment: How did you "probe" the signal? Very important!

Comment: @Andyaka i am directly inserting probes to system output. when put jumper wire or pcb same results. and i tried two different probes but same results. 

and i don't know source impedance, is there way to to measure that with simple DMM?

Comment: How do you interface your system? What kind of output driver does it have? How long is the interface cable, and how it is constructed?

Comment: @AliChen system is kind of black box, i am not allowed to open and don't have data sheet or technical detail i am reverse engineering a module interface with system which is working fine with old technology. as i told other i tried all option directly probing to system, inserted PCB and interface cable (1ft) but all have same result

Comment: You can get an idea of the source impedance by putting progressively small resistors across the signal and looking at the resulting voltage on the scope.  Start with 1K and work your way down.  Stop when you see a non-trivial amount of change in the voltage (~10%) and estimate the impedance assuming a resistive divider.  Is the signal on a cable?  If so, how long is the cable?  Can you probe the signal directly at the output of the black box?

Comment: @crj11 there is DB 25 connector on system (driver) first i made a cable of length 1ft and i check result same as picture above then i plug out cable and probe on DB25 connector again same result.

Comment: The series resistor that was suggested might help your problem, but it might work better at the DB25 end rather than at the FPGA end.  If the source has a low enough impedance to drive 100 ohms to ground at the FPGA , that might work even better.

Comment: Use short ground!!! https://e2e.ti.com/support/power_management/simple_switcher/w/simple_switcher_wiki/2243.understanding-measuring-and-reducing-output-voltage-ripple

Answer (score 4):

You can probably clean this up by using a series resistor at the FPGA end.  This will slow the rise and fall times slightly but should eliminate the overshoot and ringing.  You will probably have to determine the value experimentally, 50-100 ohms is a good starting point.

Comment: Assuming it's not the scope that is causing that.

Comment: Very true, try using a 5K resistor across the output of the signal source and probing that with the oscilloscope.  Remember that your 200ns pulse looks like it has a rise time under 10ns, so you are dealing with a 100Mhz+ signal from a signal integrity perspective.  Impedance matching matters everywhere at high frequencies.

Comment: Nope Not scope i tried different probes and scopes. all other signals are fine but this signal make problem only @Trevor_G

Comment: @DeanFranks  I will try this solution and will let you know.
how to measure impedance of system output using some simple multi-meter?

Comment: @DeanFranks then add some R at the FPGA

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a typical impedance mismatch between the driver side and transmission line. From timing of reflection/ringing, the cable length seems to be about 60 inches.  At 10 ns edge rate the transmission line effects are in place.

To solve the problem and reduce/eliminate the ringing, you need two things:

(a) use a cable with low characteristic impedance. Either use a thin coaxial cable, or flat cable with grounded adjacent wires;

(b) match the impedance of source to the characteristic impedance of the line. It can be done by placing a resistor in series with line **at driver end**. If the cable ends up as 80-100 Ohm (flat cable), and typical driver output is about 25-30 Ohms, you would need a 50-60 Ohms resistor to kill the ringing. I repeat: AT DRIVER END.

Comment: thanks for the solutions, i will try that and will let you know. these are solution when putting cable on driver end. but what about when there is no cable just driver and probe

Comment: @farhanbabar, If this waveform is inherently generated at the source driver (like under-stable OPA output on the verge of oscillations), then you have two options - either put a diode clamps (preferably Schottky) on FPGA side with a small 100-Ohm series resistor upfront. Or do nothing, FPGA will tolerate this little over/undershoots with internal clamps.

Comment: yeah i also think that it is inherently generated from driver, because i checked on driver connector i get same issue. that clamp diode and resistor both in series of driver line to FPGA?