# Overshoot and undershoot on clock signal

Tags: oscilloscope, clock

I have created a 50% duty cycle, 8 MHz clock signal on the ATmega32, 0V to 1V.

What I see when measuring this clock signal with the oscilloscope is overshoot and undershoot of about +0.2V on both sides, after every change of voltage level. It is not really a problem for my project, but I am wondering why this happens?

Added: Oscilloscope trace

[image: Oscilloscope trace]

([Source](https://ibb.co/ihyhSo))

Comment: Can you share a photo of your scope probe, and how you connect it to your circuit when you do the measurement?

Comment: i am not measuring at the moment. But i put the probe on the pad of the pcb, there was no other way to measure it. here is a part of the generated signal: https://ibb.co/ihyhSo

Comment: It's very likely the answer has to do with how your scope probe ground is connected to the circuit ground. You need to show us how they are physically connected.

Comment: I had one ground pin on the circuit and i connected the probe to it via an jumping wire. So do you think it is just more a connection problem of the probes, instead of a circuit design problem?

Comment: That's impossible to say without more detail.  But you are in a frequency range where a lot of the distortions you may see are due to transmission line effects; either in the circuit itself, or in the measuring.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [overshoot and undershoot on 3 volt pulse](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/361870/overshoot-and-undershoot-on-3-volt-pulse)

Comment: ow wow, no that's not me. but that is very coincidental haha

Comment: @soepblik - Not directly related to your overshoot/undershoot question, but as mentioned in the answer from *Tony*, your oscilloscope trace doesn't show the 50% duty cycle which you told us to expect. If that's unexpected and if it's important to you, then you might want to investigate that separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Total Signal path loop Inductance with circuit and probe capacitance will cause overshoot due to the tiny reactive load on a very high impedance probe. For this reason all signal and ground leads must be very short. Your square wave has only 20% symmetry so you may want to check your bias.

CMOS is an almost perfect voltage switch with a bipolar switch resistance RdsOn, that is low 50 ohms +-50% depending on the family 3.3V lower , vs 5V higher.

With short(1m)  10:1 probes most likely you are seeing false signal from the probe ground inductance being too long which tends to resonate with the coax capacitance when L/C >>1.

> Any signal inductance in series with a 30pF probe will cause overshoot with typ. 0.5~1nH/mm trace (signal + ground ) and probe ground wire inductance.
>
> I assume you have a decoupling cap near the IC >10nF as this will also add inductive trace length.

These are all reactive circuit impedance that affect the high slew rate voltage V(L) =LdI/dt with current not from 10 meg but the probe pF Ic=CdV/dt .

So it is normal, what you see, but if you want textbook waveforms then learning how as a Test Engineer does, is well documented in thus forum using the calibrated probe with clip and gnd wire removed using only wire tip and coaxial barrel to IC gnd with a convenient resistor wire test point .  Matched load impedance attenuates 50% or 0.1pF buffered FET differential probes also work better for maximally flat frequency response to the probe limits.